# Test is URL is valid (server response = 200)

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I am trying to check if the url provided by a user in a form is a valid one, i.e. if the server's response is 200.

I want to run the check when the user has typed something in the field and when it loses focus. Because of the same origin policy, I run the check on the server side:

Client side code:

```
    // test url when input loses focus
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        $('#target_url').focusout(function() {
            if ($('#target_url').hasClass('ng-dirty')){
                $http.post('/test-url', { target_url: scope.newJob.target_url }).success(function(response){
                    if (response === 'valid url'){
                        console.log('valid url');
                    }else{
                        console.log('url not valid');
                    }
                });
            };
        });
    });
```

Server side:

```
// url testing route
app.post('/test-url', function(req, res) {
    request(req.body.target_url, function (err, response) {
        if (response && response.statusCode === 200) {
            res.send('valid url');
        }else{
            res.send('url not valid');
        }
    })
});
```

My problem here is that the response is not printed to the console when I lose focus but only when I start typing something in another inputs. What I am doing wrong?

NB: I am using angular 1.1.5 which is why I didnt use 'ng-focus'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you need to wrap the `focusout` callback in `$scope.$apply`.

Long answer: `$.focusout` is jQuery and runs outside of Angular's digest cycle. Therefore Angular does not get the end-of-digest signal to trigget the `$http.post`. When you type in another field, a digest cycle is completed and at last the `$http.post` fires.

Suggested correction:

```
$('#target_url').focusout(function() {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        ...existing code here...
    });
});
```

Comment: That's not true for angular 1.2. Does it really work that way in angular 1.1?